# memcmp returning non zero for same (zero value) bit field structs

Tags: c++, c

I am seeing an unexpected output with memcmp when comparing two bitfields struct both containing 0 in the value. memcmp is returning non-zero result in output.

Does it mean the bits bitfield is not going to refer can remain anything? If so (causing memcmp to be unreliable) what is the best way to compare anything containing bit fields? I can have my own class or type with bit fields structures.

```
struct bitStruct{
    int b:4;
};
int test() 
{
    bitStruct s = {0};
    bitStruct zero = {0};
    cout << memcmp(&s, &zero, sizeof(s)); // this memcmp returns non-zero.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because this is c++ you could overload `==` operator and compare the structs field by field, this would be also more efficient, and certainly reliable.

Comment: How about comparing `s.b` and `zero.b`?

Comment: this being c++ doesnt change the fact that memcmp behaving unexpectedly and also assume i cant overload ==

Comment: Or can you use the `bitStruct s = { .b = 0 };` initializer and test. It shouldn't make a difference. I'm concerned since it is a bitfield that the compiler only guarantees the first 4-bits are zeroed, The rest could be indeterminate. (n that case who knows what is in bits 4-31) and a `memcmp` of all `32-bits` would fail.

Comment: @KerrekSB - The main problem i want to address is comparing two unknown types which may or may not be bit fields but may occupy any no of bits logically which is why i was trying to compare full memory bit by bit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I also agree with you, compiler is not bound to guarantee rest of the bits zeros. But then if you have lets say two block of memory represented by a few bits (by some user defined type) and want to check whether they are zero or not. how will you do that (I feel user type has to provide this info what does zero means but i was looking for a bitwise comparison as well)?

Comment: @user888270: You don't even need bit fields to have this sort of problem. A `struct { char a; int b; }` typically has three bytes of padding between `a` and `b`, and the contents of said bytes are typically undefined (even if you explicitly `memset` to 0 first, the compiler might do four byte stores to `a` sometimes, assuming it's harmless, if it thinks it's more efficient), so `memcmp` of two such structs with identical `a` and `b` values won't always return 0. `memcmp` is not general purpose when padding is involved.

Comment: Using `memset` before assigning values and comparing the memory `structs` could guarantee a "0" value for those padding bits and bits outside the bitfields. But as folks have said, not sure `memcmp` is the way to go here..

Comment: @user888270, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to overload `operator==`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `bitStruct s = { .b = 0 };` is not allowed in Standard C++  (and in Standard C it is defined to be the same as OP's original code)

Comment: `char *ps = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&s); char *pzero = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&zero); cout<<(ps[0]==pzero[0])<<endl; cout<<(ps[1]==pzero[1])<<endl; cout<<(ps[2]==pzero[2])<<endl; cout<<(ps[3]==pzero[3])<<endl;` This will tell you something but I don't know how to explain the output...

Comment: fwiw designated initializers is available in `c++20`

Answer (score 5):

There might be padding involved. `memcmp` will just compare `sizeof(s)` bytes and that's it. If padding is involved the result won't be as you expect it to be because the unnamed members of the structure will be in indeterminate stage. The comparison won't yield the same result. You can memset the structure instance with sizeof(structure type) and that will yield correct result in this scenario.

The thing you can do flawlessly in this case is to compare that bitfield only not the whole struct instance.